# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I had this working yesterday but I must of changed something now ListActiveLogins.ActiveLogins is null, what did i do?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new ListLogin(2);
        Console.WriteLine(ListLogin.LoginList.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(ListLogin.loginC);
        new ListActiveLogins(2);
        Console.WriteLine(ListActiveLogins.ActiveLogins.Length);
    }
}

public class ListLogin
{
    public static int loginC;
    public static string[,] LoginList;
    public ListLogin(int loginCount)
    {
        LoginList = new string[loginCount, 3];
        loginC = loginCount;
    }
    public int LoginCount
    {
        get { return loginC; }
    }
    public string this[int row, int col]
    {
        get
        {
            return LoginList[row, col];
        }
        set
        {
            LoginList[row, col] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ListActiveLogins
{
    public static Process[] ActiveLogins;
    public ListActiveLogins(int loginCount)
    {
        Process[] ActiveLogins = new Process[loginCount];
    }
    public Process this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return ActiveLogins[i];
        }
        set
        {
            ActiveLogins[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very poor design.  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I only started a week ago, and yeah i messed up the copy i put here too lol, public ListActiveLogins(int loginCount)
 is static in my real code dunno how i managed cut it out.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declared a local variable in your `ListActiveLogins` constructor.

This should fix it.

```
public class ListActiveLogins
{
    public static Process[] ActiveLogins;
    public ListActiveLogins(int loginCount)
    {
        ActiveLogins = new Process[loginCount];
    }
```

Comment: bah how did i add the extra Process[], its obvious now u pointed it out, everything works again thx

Comment: I'm glad we could help.  Here at stack overflow, a nice way to show gratitude is to accept the most helpful answer, (and upvote helpful answers when you can).  It also lets other helpful people know that your problem is solved.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You're making a separate local variable in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process[] ActiveLogins = new Process[loginCount];
```

is being re-declared as a local variable. Change it to:

```
ActiveLogins = new Process[loginCount];
```